# I can't listen to music anymore, is there anything that can be done?

Tags: audio

Not sure if this is on topic for this site but I'll give it a go.

I have been a 'musician' for around 16 years. I started with guitar playing, went onto college and got a degree in composition, all the while practising my guitar playing and composing digitally for several hours a day. So you could say, I'm a lover of music. Additionally, I truly love (not just like) many styles. I love contemporary classical, gypsy jazz, EDM, metal-core, Spanish & Greek traditional and a few other styles.

Anyway, recently (the last year or so) I have a big problem. Whenever I listen to a song or album I really enjoy, the songs get stuck in my head (earworm) for several days or even weeks at a time. I know this doesn't sounds like a big deal, but it is literally 24/7, I wake in the night with the song in my head and it gives my migraines and affects my everyday life.

This happens with most styles, and now I have simply subjected myself to a music fast, this seems to be the only way to alleviate it.

But this is no fun, it means I can never discover and love new music again, for fear it will plague me for weeks on end.

***Is there anything I can do to continue listening to music without this side-effect?***

If it helps or is relevant, I suffer with misophonia.

Comment: Sadly I don't think this is on topic, but I would go and see a doctor about this. There may be cures or mitigating solutions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a neurological problem and unrelated to music

Comment: @Carl Witthoft -  If the symptoms only occur after listening to music, it is related to music, isn't it?  Although neurologists may well be able to help.

Comment: I've heard that If you want to to make a song get out of your head, you need to imagine the end of this song. Not sure if this is going to help you but try it.

Comment: @Tim I agree with Carl Witthoft's vote to close; although this is *triggered* by music, it looks to be a psychological or neurological issue that will only be successfully treated by professional face to face help, not something we can usefully comment on here.

Comment: @SteveM - partially agree, except that maybe only musicians suffer from this. If it's anyone, close.

Comment: I'll just add that Oliver Sacks, neurologist and music lover, wrote extensively about this problem, for instance in _Musicophilia._  It's not limited to musicians, and it is a neurological problem, which can sometimes be treated and sometimes just goes away- or not.  Check out the literature, starting with Sacks.  Good luck.

Comment: @ScottWallace Thanks so much for the recommended reading. Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered therapeutic noise treatments, like the White Noise app?  That can be a good way to cleanse one’s pallette.